# Network install of cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

Cytoscape appears to expect it can write to its installation directory. On Linux, we do shared installs of software such the installation directories are root-owned and read-only.

Upon launch, the message:

```
Unable to update instance pid: Unable to create directory /usr/software/cytoscape/framework/instances
```

is displayed. Is this something to be concerned about? Is there an option to specify a different, usable writable directory for the instance data?

Comment: I've forwarded this question to the Cytoscape dev team. There are a couple linux users in the team. But no response yet...

Answer (score 1):

Good news. This is not a critical error message. You can ignore it.

The Cytoscape dev team now has this as a bug to fix in future versions (thanks). We'll write that properties file to the CytoscapeConfiguration folder (where all other properties are written).